# Need links to stay constrained on page in relation to image

Tags: css, html

Ok so I need some input on placing textual links to stay static to an image on a page.. 
The image is basically a cloud, with products branching out with logos and now textual links attached to each product.

what would be best way to go about this?

currently im thinking creating a div, setting the needed width and height.
Then from that. I will have the img positioned absolute within div, as well as the links all absolute positioned in same div... 
does this sound about right?

Any other approaches to this?

```
<div id="subheaderhome">

    <p class='hptext' id='wcp'> W</p>
    <p class='hptext' id='rp'> R</p>
    <p class='hptext' id='mp'> Meo</p>
    <img id="shopsol" src="images/solshairpiece.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi we can easy to figure out what you want to achieve if you can provide image or illustration about your problem

Comment: A test case on jsfiddle might also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes that approach will work but if you want the links to be positioned according to the image only,you should use position:relative over position:absolute.
position:absolute removes the element to be positioned from the normal flow of the document and places it in an exact location on the page.Meaning that the links in your case will remain in the same position even if you zoom in or out on your browser while the rest of the page changes in view.This will also make your page look messed up on a screen differently sized than yours.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're creating an image with links.  Here is another solution thinking out of the box a bit.  Incorporate the link wording into the image design itself and use an imagemap to tell the browser what parts of the image are to be treated as clickable links.  Then, the position of the links are in fact part of the image itself and you can skip over toying with CSS to get these links to behave properly.

First, you have the image tag. With the usemap attribute that must be '#mapname'.  In this code, my map's name is 'home' so my usemap attribute is "#home".

```
<nav>
    <img class="navbar" src="./images/navbar.gif" usemap="#home" alt="Home, Auto     Service, Hours & Location, Contact Info, Image Gallery" />
```

Then, you write your map out in pixel pairs.  On my page here, I have one long image of buttons rather than placing an image of the button 5 times, I made one image with 5 copies of my button.  Each area tag is covering one rectangular (shape="rect") segment of the image. In the first one here, I am starting in the top left hand corner of the image at "0,0... (x,y). The rectangle's bottom right corner is 186 pixels to the right, and 40 pixels down from that first point, so it is ...186, 40"  The href should be self explanatory to mean that those bounds link to it.

```
<map name="home">
        <area shape="rect" coords=" 0, 0, 186, 40" href="index.html" alt="Mortensen Motors Homepage" />
        <area shape="rect" coords=" 186, 0, 372, 40" href="auto_service.html" alt="Tullahoma Auto Service" />
        <area shape="rect" coords=" 372, 0, 558, 40" href="hours_and_location.html" alt="Located in Tullahoma, Tennessee" />
        <area shape="rect" coords=" 588, 0, 744, 40" href="contact_info.html" alt="Contact info" />
        <area shape="rect" coords=" 744, 0, 930, 40" href="image_gallery.html" alt="Mortensen Motors image gallery" />
    </map>
</nav>
```

So I used one image, and I made 5 links.  This would be perfect for what you're doing because the coords="" attribute is based on the image's pixels by the image file, not by actual display size.  Therefore, they do not stray from their intended areas of image coverage based on zooming.

Comment: So im attempting, although Im not sure how I can visually see where my links are being placed to begin setting coords.

Comment: To do this, you will need to first actually draw in the wording for the links in the image.  Then you will have to use your image editor to know what (x,y) pixel values are the top left and bottom right corners of each area you want to be treated as a link.  Almost every image editor should display the coordinates that the mouse is hovering over at any given point.

Comment: Also, I should clarify this; this may be a problematic way to do it if the image on the page is scaled up/down from the size that the actual image file is saved.  Then you would have to do the coords based on the CSS governed img size, which would mean that the image editing program would not be a good tool anymore.  When I said it would not modify with zoom I was referring to "ctrl+" style zooming. I know GIMP has a plugin that will output <map></map> contents for you and you can select the areas in the image editor.  Once again; change scale and it breaks.